# How to create multiple pandas profiling reports for multiple csv files in a directory? The report name should match the file name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling, data-profiling

I tried this,

```py
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

files = glob.glob("D:\home_health_services_current_data\*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.append(csv) 
    profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Profiling Report", explorative=True)
    profile.to_file("D:\proj_report\profilerep\prof_report.html")
```

Comment: Code should be enclosed in backticks ``` I've added it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks.. Noted... New in the coding world. Kindly help